# The resource was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds

Tags: http

I'm using the W3 Total Cache plugin, and have set it to minify and combine CSS and JS files.

I have also set it to use the HTTP2 preloading capabilities, though, when I load the site in Chrome, I'm seeing the following error in the console for both the CSS and JS files:

```
The resource [RESOURCE URL HERE] was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.
```

Why is that showing up? The script and the stylesheet are indeed being used, they are clearly declared in the usual places.

I looked in the Network tab of the console, and the script and the stylesheet are both in the 'memory cache' initially, and are then downloaded a second time!

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to **disable** *"HTTP/2 push"* under the Minify section of *W3 Total Cache*.

Most probably your apache server (or whatever web server you are using) does not support **http2**. The browser understands that, and it's trying to tell you that the preload is not worth it.

More about the difference between http1.1 and http2, you can find [here](https://blog.imagekit.io/still-not-using-http-2-327d56397b58).